# Oracle regexp_substr to retrieve name from where clause in string

Tags: regex, oracle

I am trying to parse a where clause in a string to return the name of the lookup_type. The where clause could be anything.

This is what I currently have:

```
select regexp_substr('where lookup_type = ''THE MILK'' ', 'lookup_type(\s*)=(\s*)''(^''*)''')
from dual
```

For some reason this does not work. Also how can I only return THE MILK from the regex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
select regexp_substr('where lookup_type = ''THE MILK'' ', 'lookup_type\s*=\s*''([^'']+)''', 1, 1, NULL, 1) as result from dual
```

See the [online demo](http://rextester.com/HBZZS60713)

**Details**

- `lookup_type` - matches a literal substring
- `\s*=\s*` - matches `=` enclosed with 0+ whitespaces
- `''` - matches a `'`
- `([^'']+)` - matches and captures 1 or more chars other than `'`
- `''` - matches a `'`

Comment: Correct, `^` means "start of string"; `[^` means "not one of the characters in brackets". As we don't need to capture anything, we can even replace `([^'']+)` by `[^'']+`.

Answer (score 0):

You could escape some quotes with `q` notation( alternative quoting mechanism)

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(q'#where lookup_type = 'THE MILK'#',
              q'#lookup_type\s*=\s*'([^']+)#', 1, 1, 'i', 1) name
FROM   dual  ;
```

[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a9a14/16)